# How to get registered filesystems list?

Tags: linux-kernel

On debugging linux kernel 3.6.11 with - "ddd vmlinux /proc/kcore" , the "file_systems" list present in fs/filesystems.c is shown empty, containing the address 0x0 .

It is supposed to contain file_system_type structures of all the registered file systems .

Why the list is empty or where else can I see the list of registered file systems ?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the kernel is not needed for that. There is a proc API that provides the information:

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

Comment: I am understanding the Virtual File System part of linux kernel. That is why I need it .